# Why isn't the GROUP BY clause in this MySQL statement throwing errors?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am using w3s as my example in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders,
    Orders.OrderDate 
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Shippers
ON Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
GROUP BY ShipperName;
```

I am confused why the above statement isn't throwing an error. How does MySQL know which `OrderDate` to use when we are aggregating by all `OrderID`?

Comment: Does it return same number of rows as if you added `orderDate` to `group by`?

Comment: `Mysql` allows aggregate queries without grouping by all non aggregate fields (shippername and orderdate in your case).  Most other databases do not allow this behavior.  When doing so though, you cannot guarantee the value of the other non aggregated columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does mysql know which OrderDate to use when we are aggregating by all OrderID?

It doesn't.  It just picks one, because it assumes you would have grouped by all the necessary columns, and any columns that weren't in the `GROUP BY` and weren't subject to any aggregate functions would have the same values for each group.

It's non-standard behavior that works as an optimization, allowing the server to "leak" one of the values through from each group in the source rows into the result-set, reducing the size of the data the `GROUP BY` has to manage.  *Which* source row's value is used for each group is undefined, so this is intended to be used only in queries where the non-grouped columns are functionally dependent on the grouped columns... because, in that case, "which" row doesn't matter, because they're all the same within each group.

> MySQL extends the standard SQL use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means that the [queries excluding non-aggregated columns are] legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the `GROUP BY` are the same for each group. **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.** Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an `ORDER BY` clause. [emphasis added]
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

You can disable this behavior by including [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in @@SQL_MODE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).